# div width auto collapsing when using overlayScrollbars.js

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having an issue with [overlayScrollbars](https://github.com/KingSora/OverlayScrollbars).

I have a simple layout, fixed left panel and footer with resizable (and scrollable) content.

Bare bones css works as expected just fine : [CodePen1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKJPwX)

But when I try to add overlayScrollbars to style the scrollbar the content div width collapses : [CodePen2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeZwBB)

Any ideas how to fix this?

HTML

```
<div id="panel"></div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #808080;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

#panel {
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  width: 255px;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#content {
  width: auto;   
  float: left;
  margin-left: 255px;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background: #F1F1F1;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 20px 90px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

NB - I've omitted the inline JS & CSS for overlayScrollbars that is included in the pen (there is no CDN available).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the `float` and `position` properties in the `#content` div.
Removing them and then adding a `z-index` to the `#footer` div fixed it.

[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKoePq)

```
#content {
  width: auto;   
  margin-left: 255px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  z-index: 10;
}
```